# How to create an Django ordered list

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class Instrument(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

The table looks like this:

```
name   | category |
---------------------
violin | string   |
viola  | string   |
flute  | woodwind |
oboe   | woodwind |
trumpet| brass    |
```

I would like to output in my template an ordered list like:

```
   String: 
     Violin
     Viola
   Woodwind:
     flute
     oboe
   Brass:
     trumpet
```

Is there an easy way to display this once I have query the Instrument object?

Comment: I don't see any *"specific ordering logic"* in your desired output. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `defaultdict` to accumulate a list of instrument names for each category.

In your view:

```
from collections import defaultdict
instruments_by_category = defaultdict(list)

for instrument in Instrument.objects.all().values('name', 'category'):
    instruments_by_category[instrument["category"]].append(instrument["name"])
```

In your template:

```
{% for category, names in instruments_by_category.items %}
  {{ category }}:
  {% for name in names %}
    {{ name }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can figure out the HTML to get the layout you want.

Comment: I keep getting errors on this. instruments_by_category[instrument["category"]].append(instrument["name"])

Comment: I get the following output: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'instrument__category': ['instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name', 'instrument__name']})

Comment: What's the output of: `Instrument.objects.all().values('name', 'category')`?